# C simulation using array crashes when big number of nodes is used

Tags: c

I am trying to run a really simple simulation of infected nodes in a network.

The problem is that when I change the number of nodes to a big one (eg 1.000.000) the executable crashes and the results I get stop at node number 32768.

I guess that it has to do with the maximum number int datatype can store.
Is there any way to avoid this without using malloc?
I have tried to change the datatype from int to double but doesnt seem to help.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#define INFECTED 1
#define HEALTHY 0
#define N 100000

int main(){

srand(time(NULL)); 
int infected;
int nodes[N] = { HEALTHY };
int totalinfected = 1;
int currentinfected = 1;
nodes [ rand() % N ] = INFECTED;
int timestep = 1;
FILE *ptr;
ptr = fopen ("results.csv", "w+");

while (totalinfected < N) {
    for (infected = 1; infected<=currentinfected; infected++) {
        int node = rand() % N;
        if (nodes[node] == HEALTHY){
            nodes[node] = INFECTED;
            totalinfected++;
        }
    }

    currentinfected = totalinfected;
    fprintf(ptr , "%d; %d\n", timestep, totalinfected);
    timestep++;

}

fclose(ptr);

printf("success all infected\n");
return 0;

}
```

Comment: Probably the array is too big for the stack - put it on the heap

Comment: ...Or, increase your stack size.  Common thing.  (my IDE has a setting to increase maximum stack size for executable ).

Comment: WHat's wrong with using malloc?  That's what it is there for.

Comment: Try `static` like `static int nodes[N] = { HEALTHY };`

Comment: But a stack overflow would crash right away when the array is created. The remark that te simulation stops at node 32768 (`1 << 15`) makes me suspect that the random number generator cannot generate large values, so that the rear part of the array never gets infected.. Print out the value of `RAND_MAX` to check that.

Comment: Why *without `malloc`*?

Comment: @AGNGazer heap memory is slower than stack memory. For a large simulation, memory access could be a very important factor in speed optimization.

Answer (score 2):

The problem had nothing to do with *the maximum number int datatype can store*.  (which by the way is *[2,147,483,647](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s3f49ktz.aspx)*, much larger than your value for `N`). And, unless you have a very small maximum stack size defined in your environment, I do not think stack size was the problem.

From running your code on my system, it appears that the range of the *[rand()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_rand.htm)* function was really the culprit.  Its range is determined by RAND_MAX, which actual value is implementation specific.  In the comments, it was suggested that you check its value.  On my system it is defined as:

```
#define RAND_MAX 32767
```

As a result, all progress was stopped on my system when `32767` of the `100000` array locations available were processed.  The only way to move beyond this point is to have a random number generator with a range sufficient to populate all `100000` locations.

I tested this with a wonky (but in this case effective) modified number generator *based on rand()*:

```
int a_bigger_rand_max(void)
{
    int a, b;
    a = rand();
    b = rand(); 
    return a*(RAND_MAX+1)+b;
}
```

Which will generate up to `(RAND_MAX+1)^2-1` numbers.

Other than adding this function, and its prototype at top, this was the only line that was changed (in your `main()` function):

```
int node = rand() % N;
```

To:

```
int node = a_bigger_rand_max() % N;
```

This resulted in a successful run.  (assuming that the criteria for success is the .csv file being populated, and a printout of `success all infected\n` on teh console.